# Insert an application to another one.C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to insert one application for example to another application window using WinForms .NET application. I need application A to run in application B in a window of application B.

**UPD**
I would like to run .exe file in window of my program.

Comment: Have you tried importing the project(s) from (A) into (B) and changing your code so that A's output is shown in a Window in Project B?

Comment: At this moment I dont know if I have access to source code for project A. (And I dont know in what language project A have been written)

Comment: Here is another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950515/winform-lock-other-application-inside-form

Comment: Exe is a separate process. As long as you just want to launch one .exe from another .exe then it is simple, but if you want 2 exe to share the process then you need lot of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have not its source code, i think it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate answer: [Embedding a winform within a winform (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301678/embedding-a-winform-within-a-winform-c)

As stated in the answer to that question, you would be better moving your logic into a `UserControl` and hosting that control from either application in one WinForms window.

Comment: I think It is possible if you have source code of both applications. I would like to run .exe file in window of my program.

Comment: Is there a particular reason or need to have it setup that way?

Comment: Yes, my client wish to do this.