# Is there a way to show part of one form on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a form. All I want to do is display a section of that form on another form.
I don't want it to be functional or anything. I basically just want it to be a picture.
Is that possible, and if so, how?

Like

```
display = new display(form, new rectangle(X1, X2, Y1, Y2));
```

Is that a possibility?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301678/embedding-a-winform-within-a-winform-c

Comment: @kol He just wants the image; it shouldn't be functional.

Comment: @Servy You mean he wants to display the screenshot of a form on another *without creating it*? You would have to create the form once, create a screenshot and save it, to be able to use it in an app, which you does not want to create the form.

Comment: @kol He never said that the form shouldn't ever be created; just that a user shouldn't be able to interact with it.  My point is simply that the linked question doesn't solve the question as asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myWidth, myHeight);
myForm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(x, y, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
```

And then pass this bitmap to the other form.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. It seems like just what I need. The next trick is going to be finding the coordinates to take the picture from.

Comment: You got me on the correct track. I had to use something similar (Graphics.CopyFromScreen()) and I still need to figure out the positioning, but it did work. Using drawtobitmap just got me a blank screen and a webbrowser component (which is what I needed to take a partial picture of) doesn't support drawtobitmap. The solution I found is here:
http://www.deepakkapoor.net/programmatically-take-screenshot-using-c/