# How to capture a specific HTML Element as an image?

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I asked a question similar to this here:
[Is there a way to show part of one form on another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612589/is-there-a-way-to-show-part-of-one-form-on-another-form)

This would work great if I could guarantee that every single person who uses this application uses the same monitor as I do.

But I'm a realist so I'll get to the nitty gritty.

If I can (which I can) identify the specific `HtmlElement` of the `WebBrowser` control document that houses what I want to create an image from, is there any way that I can create an image from that specific `HtmlElement`?

I've seen some stuff about `IExtractImage` but everything I've seen makes my head hurt a little bit. If someone could dumb that down (if that's what I'm looking for) so that I could use that, that would be super good.

To be a bit more clear what I'm hoping for is something like `HtmlElement.DrawToBitmap()`

Comment: When you say "that specific HtmlElement" it makes your question sound very vague. Maybe we could help you more if you share the HTML.

Comment: HTML Element Objects are HTML Element Object. There's no structure difference from one to the next no matter what their HTML code, what website they are on, or anything else. The method used to capture one HTML Element Object should be identical to the method used to capture any other HTML Element Object. If it helps, the object in question is a table data row (<tr></tr>) and I am working with C#.